# KeyboardAvoidingView should be bottom of view

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with using `KeyboardAvoidingView`. I have a modal with that shows from bottom of screen. And it has a input then i focus my input Modal goes to center to screen. What i want is that modal should be positioned above of virtual keyboard. Here is a example:

```
return (
    <AppModalContext.Consumer>
      {(context: ModalContext) => (
        <Modal
          onBackdropPress={() => context.isBackPress() && context.hide()}
          style={context.getStyle()}
          onBackButtonPress={() => context.hide()}
          coverScreen={false}
          isVisible={context.isVisible()}
          swipeDirection={context.getDirection()}>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior="padding"
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'lime' }}>
            {context.getContent()}
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </AppModalContext.Consumer>
  );
```

Result is:

[image]

What did i do wrong ? any advice ?

Comment: try keeping your whole modal in KeyboardAvoidingView.

Comment: You mean modal inside to KeyboardAvoidingView ?